# Using \lstinline inside a new command or environment

Tags: macros, listings

I use the `listings` package to render code in LaTeX documents. I am trying to define a new command or a new environment that uses \lstinline inside. I have read numerous questions about this on StackExchange, but have not found a solution to my problem.

I want a macro `\code` such that this code:

```
\code{a $\leq$ b}
```

expands to this:

```
\begin{definition}
  \lstinline[mathescape=true]{a $\leq$ b}
\end{definition}
```

The `NewDocumentCommand` from the `xparse` package seemed promising but this doesn't compile.

```
\NewDocumentCommand\code{v}{\lstinline[mathescape=true]{#1}}
\code{a $\leq$ b}
```

The error:

```
ERROR: Undefined control sequence.

--- TeX said ---
\lst@arg ->a $\
               leq$ b
l.6 \code{a $\leq$ b}
```

So, my question is: is it possible to warn LaTeX that the argument of `\code` should not be expanded until it is passed to `\lstinline`?

Thank you,

Pierre

Comment: you can not use verbatim commands (including listings commands) in the argument of another command, this is just a basic rule about how tex parsing works.

Comment: You could do `\newcommand\code{\lstinline[mathescape=true]}` so that the argument was not scanned before listinline starts.

Comment: Yes I have seen this solution elsewhere. However, it doesn't allow me to wrap this inside a definition environment for example.

Comment: verbatim changes the way that characters are tokenized it has no effect on tokens that have already been read. that is just how tex works.

Comment: I understand that what I have tried does not work. Are you saying that there is no way (even with obscure voodoo TeX black magic) to achieve the macro expansion I described in my question?

Comment: there is no way to do what you ask, you can however always do _something_ for example arrange (using something like the first comment) to grab the argument verbatim but then save it in a box rather than immediately typeset, then use that box in your real command.

Comment: OK that seems to be an interesting solution. Can you provide some code or documentation to the relevant commands to "save it in a box rather than immediately typeset" and then to "use that box"? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it a bit simpler by requiring double `{{` it's probably possible to avoid that with some more effort, or use an environment form or explicit end marker eg `\code ... \stopcode` which would be easier.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

%\code{a $\leq$ b}



\hrule
\begin{quote}
  \lstinline[mathescape=true]{a $\leq$ b \zzz}
\end{quote}
\hrule

\bigskip

% gobble a {
\def\code{\afterassignment\xcode\let\tmp}

% run lstinline and save inside box0, call \setcode when done
\def\xcode{\setbox0\hbox\bgroup\aftergroup\setcode
 \lstinline[mathescape=true]}

% does the environment required, using \usebox0 to use the saved text

\def\setcode{\hrule\begin{quote}\usebox0\end{quote}\hrule}

\code{{a $\leq$ b \zzz}}

\end{document}
```

---

or with an argument as requested in comments

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

%\code{a $\leq$ b}



\hrule
\begin{quote}
  \lstinline[mathescape=true]{a $\leq$ b \zzz}
\end{quote}
\hrule

\bigskip

% gobble a {
\def\code#1{\def\savedlabel{#1}\afterassignment\xcode\let\tmp}

% run lstinline and save inside box0, call \setcode when done
\def\xcode{\setbox0\hbox\bgroup\aftergroup\setcode
 \lstinline[mathescape=true]}

% does the environment required, using \usebox0 to use the saved text

\def\setcode{\hrule\begin{quote}\label{\savedlabel}\fbox{\savedlabel}\\%
    \usebox0\end{quote}\hrule}

\code{hmm}{{a $\leq$ b \zzz}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer, David. This does exactly what I asked for. 
However, I'm afraid I didn't ask what I really wanted ;)
I would like `\code` to take as a parameter a label name to place inside the definition. I've tried naive stuff, but since I don't understand the TeX code you posted, I'm not sure how to do this.
Thanks.

Comment: @user2357463 see update:-)

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot! Now it's exactly what I need!
I'll try to understand this code someday.