# lstinline inside new environment not able to escape maths

Tags: listings

I am trying to create a new environment using `\lstinline` from the `listings` package.
But it does not escape maths.

I have tried solutions in a couple of questions - [1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/298133/using-lstinline-inside-a-new-command-or-environment), [2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/179606/lstinline-macro-inside-another-environment/179607#comment414791_179607), but not able to get it working for my problem.

Below is the code that I am trying and its output

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{parskip}
\lstset{mathescape,keepspaces}

\newenvironment{newEnv}[1]{\lstinline[basicstyle=\bfseries\ttfamily,escapeinside={||},mathescape=true]{#1}\\
}
{}

\begin{document}
    \lstinline{let $v_1$ = 10 in $v_1$ + $v_2$}

    \begin{newEnv}{let $v_1$ = 10 in $v_1$ + $v_2$}
      Some random text.
    \end{newEnv}
\end{document}
```

#### Output

[image]

#### Update: LaTeX escape not working

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{parskip}
\lstset{mathescape,keepspaces}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{newEnv}{v}
  {%
    \begingroup
    \everyeof{\noexpand}%
    \expandafter
    \endgroup
    \scantokens
      {%
        \lstinline
          [basicstyle=\bfseries\ttfamily,escapeinside=||,mathescape=true]%
          {#1}%
      }%
    \\
  }
  {}

\begin{document}
    \lstinline
      [basicstyle=\bfseries\ttfamily,escapeinside=||,mathescape=true]%
      {let $v_1$ = 10 in $v_1$ + $v_2$ |this should be escaped\textsuperscript{3}|}

    \begin{newEnv}{let $v_1$ = 10 in $v_1$ + $v_2$ |this should be escaped\textsuperscript{3}|}
      Some random text.
    \end{newEnv}
\end{document}
```

#### Output

[image: Output]

Comment: This can't work because the environment grabs the argument with normal category codes and forwards the argument. But `\lstinline` needs to read the tokens with other category codes (but tokenisation already took place by the time `\lstinline` starts).

Answer (score 2):

The following works by grabbing the argument verbatim and forwarding that to `\lstinline` (wrapped inside `\scantokens` so that `\lstinline` can assign whichever category codes it needs).

This solution only works for single-line verbatim arguments. If you need it to work for multi-line arguments as well I can adapt things (but it's a bit more work).

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{parskip}
\lstset{mathescape,keepspaces}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{newEnv}{v}
  {%
    \begingroup
    \everyeof{\noexpand}%
    \expandafter
    \endgroup
    \scantokens
      {%
        \lstinline
          [basicstyle=\bfseries\ttfamily,escapeinside={||},mathescape=true]%
          {#1}%
      }%
    \\
  }
  {}

\begin{document}
    \lstinline
      [basicstyle=\bfseries\ttfamily,escapeinside={||},mathescape=true]%
      {let $v_1$ = 10 in $v_1$ + $v_2$}

    \begin{newEnv}{let $v_1$ = 10 in $v_1$ + $v_2$}
      Some random text.
    \end{newEnv}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Math escape is working as expected but the latex escape is not working inside ||. e.g. if I add `|\textsuperscript{3}|` in the parameter of newEnv it's not rendering properly. Any suggestion for that?

Comment: @aaryan that doesn't work inside a `{}`-delimited `\lstinline`, not the fault of this code. Change the delimiters of the `\lstinline` call to something other than `{}` that you're absolutely sure will never show up in the argument (e.g., `:` if that is never used in your verbatim stuff, or `"`). Btw. the grabbing of the environment with `{}` is fine for this, but you could change this to two matching symbols as well.

Comment: Even after changing the delimiters it somehow does not escape the LaTeX code, what is wrong here? I have pasted the updated code in the question.

Comment: @aaryan your updated code doesn't show any changed delimiters...

Comment: Instead of `{||}`, now, there is only `||`, and text enclosed inside `||` is not able to escape LaTeX code. e,g, it is not rendering `\textsuperscript{3}`.

Comment: @aaryan try to create some code that has the desired behaviour with `\lstinline`. If you manage that, use the same code for your environment. You'll have problems using stuff like `\textsuperscript{3}` in the escaped code if you use `{<code-argument>}` with `\lstinline`, instead use `\lstinline[<options>]:<code-argument>:` (or any other delimiter than `:`).